# How can I extract the maximum values?

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset values of data frame in R. First, I want to select **"≥35%" categories**. Second, among others after the first step, I would like to choose **the maximun value of "Percent" values**. Here is some parts of my original CSV file.

```
 ID   Code  Code2  Percent   category
A001  0123  10000     0        <35%
A001  0123  20000    66        ≥35%
A001  0123  30000    34        <35%
B001  7894  52003   100        ≥35%
C001  2020  35001    20        <35%
C001  2020  35002    20        <35%
C001  2020  35003    20        <35%
C001  2020  35004    20        <35%
C001  2020  35005    20        <35%
```

However, I hope to filter my data frame as illustrated below.

```
 ID   Code  Code2  Percent   category
A001  0123  20000    66        ≥35%
B001  7894  52003   100        ≥35%
C001  2020  35001    20        <35%
C001  2020  35002    20        <35%
C001  2020  35003    20        <35%
C001  2020  35004    20        <35%
C001  2020  35005    20        <35%
```

Actually, I tried some R codes in order to make a result, which I want to get.

```
X <- subset(dataframe, category =="≥35%" | Percent == max(Percent))
```

But this code did not give the result; thus, I used another code.

```
X <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dataframe, as.factor(dataframe$ID)), function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$Percent),])}))
```

Nonetheless, it did not work, either.

Comment: The way you describe it you really don't care about which is greater than or equal to 35% for each ID since you want to keep the maximum rows despite them being less than 35%. This can be solved by modifying your code slightly extracting all corresponding to the max for its respective ID: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dataframe, dataframe$ID), function(x) x[x$Percent==max(x$Percent),]))`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @henrik_ibsen I can filter "≥35%" values. However, I have no idea how to set R codes for the maximun result. First of all, I extracted ID values which have "≥35%" values. These IDs are A001 and B001 in this case. Then, I chose an ID, which has only "<35%" values, ans this ID is C001. However, if I use 'do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dataframe, as.factor(dataframe$ID)), function(x) {returnx[which.max(x$Percent),])}))' or the R code, which you gave advice, the result shows only the upper line of the C001 values, not the all 20 percent.

Comment: @henrik_ibsen My guessing was that the maximum value of the C001 should have Code2, from 35001 to 3500 because all values of C001 are 20 percents. Nevertheless, 'which.max()' function gave the only 35001 Code2 of ID C001. Did you understand what I said? and thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure why the code I provided is not working for you. It is fundamentally different in how it deals with the maximum values and indexing compared to yours. It works when I do it and reproduces exactly the second data.frame of your question. `which.max()` only determines the index of the first max. Mine (should...) determine the index of all equal to the max for each data.frame in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

#processing on data where category is equal to '<35%' ONLY
df_le <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!any(category == '≥35%')) %>%
  filter(Percent==max(Percent)) %>%
  data.frame()

#final data by combining both categories
final_df <- rbind(df %>%
                    filter(category=='≥35%'),
                  df_le)
final_df
```

Output is:

```
    ID Code Code2 Percent category
1 A001  123 20000      66    >=35%
2 B001 7894 52003     100    >=35%
3 C001 2020 35001      20     <35%
4 C001 2020 35002      20     <35%
5 c001 2020 35003      20     <35%
6 C001 2020 35004      20     <35%
7 C001 2020 35005      20     <35%
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A001", "A001", "A001", "B001", "C001", 
"C001", "c001", "C001", "C001"), Code = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 7894L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Code2 = c(10000L, 20000L, 
30000L, 52003L, 35001L, 35002L, 35003L, 35004L, 35005L), Percent = c(0L, 
66L, 34L, 100L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), category = c("<35%", 
">=35%", "<35%", ">=35%", "<35%", "<35%", "<35%", "<35%", "<35%"
)), .Names = c("ID", "Code", "Code2", "Percent", "category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```